# Protocol violation on C#, attempting to connect to SHOUTCast

Tags: c#, webrequest, shoutcast, webresponse

I am making a program on Visual C#, attempting to connect to a Shoutcast radio and download the audio. However, I get a protocol violation error on the GetResponse() function.
I've heard that Shoutcast is not a common HTTP protocol, and I didn't find any data related to special connections.
I have something like this in my code:

```
private void downloadPart()
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest conn;
        System.Net.WebResponse connResp;
        System.IO.Stream readStream = null;
        System.IO.FileStream writeStream;
        int bufferSize = 8192;
        try
        {
            conn = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(this.caminhoURL);
            connResp = conn.GetResponse();
            readStream = connResp.GetResponseStream();
            writeStream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
            int length;
            byte[] buffer = new Byte[bufferSize];
            do
            {
                length = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Working");
                readStream.Flush();
            } while (length > 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fluxoLeitura != null)
            {
                fluxoLeitura.Close();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Done");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tested this function to download a simple file and it worked.
I know that the stream is continuous so I can't download it all in a single file, I just need to know how to configure the connection.
How should I do this?

Comment: You can't use WebRequest for SHOUTCast's ICY protocol http://www.indexcom.com/streaming/player/SHOUTcast.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, EZI. Your link helped me a lot. So all I need is to create a HttpWebRequest, and configure the HTTP GET method ? Is that it?